# Strange behavior of MySQL commands NOT IN | GROUP_CONCAT?

Tags: mysql, sql

I really confused with next behavior of MySQL commands. As you see my SQL statement pretty simple.

SQL statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_1
WHERE POSITION_ID NOT IN (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ID_OBJECT)
    FROM TABLE_2
)
```

This part:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ID_OBJECT)
FROM TABLE_2
```

Return me: `5636,4697,2174,5559,3180,4102,4192,7598,5922,7432`

But when I check SQL statement, I see record which has POSITION_ID=3180. How it happens? There shouldn't have been a record like this, because we ruled it out. How wrong I did? Maybe I missed some symbol?

**EDIT**:

I think problem can be in `GROUP_CONCAT` command. It probably puts the result in apostrophes like this which is not what I want:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_1
WHERE POSITION_ID NOT IN ("5636,4697,2174,5559,3180,4102,4192,7598,5922,7432")
```

I need such code:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_1
WHERE POSITION_ID NOT IN (5636,4697,2174,5559,3180,4102,4192,7598,5922,7432)
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result? that really help

Comment: @D-Shih Hello! Can you check my post post again pls. I added my assumptions. The last code without apostrophes is correct.

Comment: I write an answer you can try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GROUP_CONCAT` function returns a string value if your use `NOT IN` by `GROUP_CONCAT(ID_OBJECT)` will compare with the string result.

You can try to use `NOT IN` with subquery to make it.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_1
WHERE POSITION_ID NOT IN (
    SELECT ID_OBJECT
    FROM TABLE_2
)
```

Comment: Thats what I am talking about. I knew that was the problem was with `GROUP_CONCAT`. Thank you for your time, bro.

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek no, the problem was with how you used group_concat()

Comment: @Shadow you are absolutely right! My bad.